# MySQL - Alter table to automatically put in a UUID

Tags: mysql

Ok, I know I've done this before.  But I cannot for the life of me figure it out.  I created a table.  One of the columns is labled "LogID", it is also the primary key.

How do I alter it so that this column generates a UUID for each new entry?

Thanks

Answer (score 23):

Just create a trigger to run **before** insert to generate the UUID for the given column.

```
CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_mytable
  BEFORE INSERT ON mytable
  FOR EACH ROW
  SET new.LogID = uuid();
```

Answer (score 3):

The [UUID()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid) expression generates a UUID when called.

Unfortunately (AFAIK anyway) MySQL won't allow expressions as a default value for a field. As a work around, you could always set the field to default null and have a trigger that updates the field with a UUID on insert.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure [you still can't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270309/can-i-use-a-function-for-a-default-value-in-mysql), actually.  I would seriously consider *not* using a UUID as a primary key, instead using a slimmer, nicer data type like `INT`.  You can add your UUID as a separate column and update it via a `TRIGGER`, if that suits you.

Comment: Integers break down if you need records to be unique across your database.

Comment: I would suspect there is a larger model design or chosen tool issue if requirements are dictating the engine storage pattern at that level.  Having the UUID as a separate column is actually a best of both worlds solution in this case.

Comment: UUID gets bloated once formatted for humans. If you want to use a UUID as a primary key then strip the dashes and unhex it. If you need the human formatted version you could add a generated column to the table. `SELECT LENGTH(UNHEX(REPLACE(UUID(),'-','')))` = 16 bytes binary. Still bigger than `INT` but much better than `VARCHAR(36)`

Comment: Bad advice, miknik. Your database will scale terribly if you use a UUID as a primary key. Might as well have 16 separate integer columns as a compound primary key. And index fragmentation galore! Your primary key is now random. If you do, don't use foreign keys. Joins change from O(n) to O(n^2). Two joins from O(n log10(n)) to O(n^3). Replace n with 100,000 and subtract the difference.

Answer (score 2):

I just decided to include the UUID() command on the insert from my application.

Thanks all.