# How to insert a record with generated identifiers using UUID()?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, trigger, mariadb

## The Problem

### Overview

So I'm trying to create records that have:

1. id (primary key, auto-increment)
2. 4 columns that are each a different UUID generated using the MySQL
   functions: `REPLACE(UUID(), '-', '')`. These 'obfuscated keys' are
   used for external lookup in other tables. *REPLACE() is used to
   strip the dashes (-) from the UUID generated by MySQL, which is
   required to later transform the UUID into a binary format.  Please
   don't worry about that!!!*

The Table structure is as follows:
`+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field           | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id              | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| info            | varchar(32) | YES  | UNI | NULL    |       |
| note            | varchar(32) | YES  | UNI | NULL    |       |
| auth            | varchar(32) | YES  | UNI | NULL    |       |
| test            | varchar(32) | YES  | UNI | NULL    |       |
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+`

### Environment

```
OS         : CentOS 7
Database   : MariaDB/MySQL
DB Version : 5.5
```

---

## Partial Solutions Found

I have found a few articles that seem to point "a direction", however I have been unable to solve this.

- [Trigger before insert](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/57293/mysql-alter-table-to-automatically-put-in-a-uuid) : Partially works, but only on the first column.  The MySQL error is: `Error Code: 1235. This version of MariaDB doesn't yet support 'multiple triggers with the same action time and event for one table'`
    Also requires the columns to allow `null` defaults.  Seems like too much of a band-aid hack.

  ```
  CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_infoid 
    BEFORE INSERT ON user 
    FOR EACH ROW 
        SET new.info = replace(uuid(),'-',''); 
  CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_noteid 
    BEFORE INSERT ON user 
    FOR EACH ROW 
        SET new.note = replace(uuid(),'-',''); 
  CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_authid 
    BEFORE INSERT ON user 
    FOR EACH ROW 
        SET new.auth = replace(uuid(),'-',''); 
  CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_testid 
    BEFORE INSERT ON user 
    FOR EACH ROW 
        SET new.test = replace(uuid(),'-','');
  ```
- [Direct using insert](http://mysqlserverteam.com/storing-uuid-values-in-mysql-tables/) : Works, but means that the logic is not contained in the database.  Also, I get a MySQL warning `warning(s): 1364 Field 'id' doesn't have a default value`.

  ```
  INSERT INTO `meanlearn`.`students` 
  (`info`, 
  `note`, 
  `auth`, 
  `test`) 
  VALUES 
  (REPLACE(UUID(),'-',''), 
  REPLACE(UUID(),'-',''), 
  REPLACE(UUID(),'-',''), 
  REPLACE(UUID(),'-',''));
  ```

---

## Preliminary Conclusion / Request for Solutions

I'm sure I'm missing something.  Any and all suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: This isn't SO. Not much poo-poo here ;)

Comment: By the way, the error you got on the multiple trigger, shows a direction to a possible solution. Create one trigger, that sets all 4 columns.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ could you show me a rewrite on using the trigger to set all 4 columns using the single trigger?  It still leaves the structure as the columns are null-able, which is not really ideal.

Comment: I've added an answer. To be honest, I haven't really understood why you would need 4 UUIDs in a table, so I can't think of any other solution. Perhaps you can explain your situation a bit more.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ The short answer is to obfuscate linked record on external tables. Each uuid is a lookup on another external table. I am envisioning storing the external ids as binary and indexed, but i need the human readable for logging chain of access. The stored uuids will be dehexed and converted prior to lookup externally. Does that kind of makes sense? I know it's a bit convoluted but it was requested by my client. I will follow up on your answer shortly. Thanks a ton though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to vercome the multiple trigger error would be ot use one trigger - and not 4 - to set the new UUID values:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_on_user_set_uuids
  BEFORE INSERT ON user 
  FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
      SET new.info = replace(uuid(),'-',''); 
      SET new.note = replace(uuid(),'-',''); 
      SET new.auth = replace(uuid(),'-',''); 
      SET new.test = replace(uuid(),'-',''); 
    END ;  //
DELIMITER ;
```

It would also be good idea to store the UUIDs in `BINARY(16)` columns instead of `VARCHAR(32)`. Saves 16x4 bytes per row (plus 16 per row multiplied by the number of simple indexes on the columns) and some speed for not considering collations and character sets. And I assume you had the varchar column as ASCII and not UTF-8 which would be a real waste.

Comment: So this does work, but (of course) it generates a warning 
`1 row(s) affected, 4 warning(s): 1364 Field 'info' doesn't have a default value 1364 Field 'note' doesn't have a default value 1364 Field 'auth' doesn't have a default value 1364 Field 'test' doesn't have a default value`
Do you think I would be better off generating the UUID's externally and passing them in to the insert statement?  I was trying to insulate my web-app from having to directly handle this logic, but maybe it is better to do that.  FYI, I am using Node.js, Angular/Express, Sequalize as my primary Web Development stack